# When is $(f(x),d)$ a complete metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

$(X,d)$ is a complete metric space with a metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. $f$ is a continuous function. What condition f should satisfy such that $(f(x),d)$ is a complete metric space?

I think $f$ is a uniformly continuous, but I don't know whether it is right.

Comment: In order for $(f(X),d)$ to be a complete metric space $f(X)$ must be closed in $X$. What sort of requirement does this impose on $f$?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. What is codomain of $f$? Did you mean $X$ with the metric $d'(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$?

Comment: Of course one condition is that $|f(x)-f(y)|$ define a metric on X. :)

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not 1-1 then $|f(x)-f(y)|$ does not define a metric on $X$ as you have distinct points having distance zero from one another. Constant functions are uniformly continuous, so your guess is wrong.

I believe the answer is that $f$ be $1-1$ and proper... that is the inverse image of any compact set under $f$ is compact. For metric spaces compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness.  If $f$ is not proper then there is a sequence $x_n \in X$ with $f(x_n)$ convergent even though $x_n$ isn't.

On the other hand if $f$ is $1-1$ and proper, let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in the "$f$-metric".  This means in particular the sequence $f(x_n)$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ and has a limit $y$.  The set $\{f(x_n)\}\cup \{y\}$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ so it has compact inverse image.  Since $x_n$ is in this set, it has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$  Since $f$ is continuous this sequence is convergent in the $f$ metric, and if a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges then so does the Cauchy sequence. Therefore $X$ in the "$f$-metric$ is complete.

There are probably other solutions that work, and since this is a homework problem the correct solution is the one that fits in with where you are in the class. Also I took some not so baby steps in my proof, so you need to fill in the details to be at the proper level to get credit for the solution.